# Laravel route model binding for just one route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a controller with 8 methods. Seven of them use this statement:

```
$item = Item::findOrFail($id);
```

However, only one needs a different query:

```
$item = Item::with('subitem')->findOrFail($id);
```

I would like to define a route model binding for the first seven of these methods, however, is there a way to somehow tell the Laravel that for the last method I want the ID injected instead of an instance of the Item class? Currently I'm doing the following but its quite bad:

```
$item = Item::with('subitem')->findOrFail($item->id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it easily only by changing the parameter name in your route that is being used for model binding, for example, why not use `$item` (or something like that) in the routes for which you need model binding so you can bind the model to routes which contains `$item` parameter, for example:

```
Route::post('items/{item}', 'ItemController@update');
```

When binding the model to route, use something like this:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    $router->model('item', 'App\Item');
}
```

So, onle when `item` parameter is found as route parameter, the `Item` model would be bound but for the route which needs an `ID`, use route declaration like this one (Using `id` as parameter):

```
Route::post('items/{id}', 'ItemController@whatever');
```

In `ItemController@whatever` method you'll get the id from route:

```
public function whatever($id)
{
    // $id would be an integer value for $id not a model
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Although this isn't quite as elegant as I exptected. Seems that I won't use route model binding anymore, it's too basic..